# Dropping a Measure Group in C#

Tags: c#, ssas

I am trying to delete a measure group A from the cube in C# using

```
//measureGroup is of type AS.MeasureGroup
measureGroup.Drop();
```

Since this measure group A exists in a many to many relationship in another measure group, how can I delete this relationship in c#. I want to drop this measure group and not drop the other measure groups as well.

Is there anything that I need to do before I drop the Measure Group?

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried it? In my opinion it should only affect the Dimensions which are using this many-to-many relationship. I.e. if you drop the intermediate MeasureGroup, you will not be able to get Results from the Many-To-Many dimension. If there are other dimensions using the target Measuregroup they should still be working. If you remove the target MeasureGroup and there are other dimensions related to the intermediate MeasureGroup, they too should still be functional.

But I must admit that I'm not really an expert when it comes to Analysis Services.

Maybe you post a short example of what you're trying to do?